Why is my MIPS program not printing anything?
I have written the following MIPS program to print prime numbers below 1000.
# Constants
ARRAY_LEN = 1000

main:

    # TODO: add your code here
    li  $t0, 2
    li  $t1, 0
    li  $t2, 2
    li  $t3, 0
    li  $t4, 0
    
loop_cond:
    bge $t0, ARRAY_LEN, end

loop:
    lb  $t1, prime($t0)
    bnez    $t1, counter_add
    
print:
    li  $v0, 1
    move    $a0, $t1
    syscall

loop2:
    mul $t4, $t0, $t2
    bge $t4, ARRAY_LEN, counter_add
    sb  $zero, prime($t4)
    addi    $t2, $t2, 1
    j   loop2
    
counter_add:
    addi    $t0, $t0, 1
    j   loop_cond
    
end:
    li  $v0, 0
    jr  $ra         # return 0;

    .data
prime:
    .byte   1:ARRAY_LEN     # uint8_t prime[ARRAY_LEN] = {1, 1, ...};

But when I run this program it doesn't print anything and I'm not sure which part I did wrong.

Your array is initialized with 1s, and you skip over printing and looping for nonzero elements. (You also want to print $t0 - the index - rather than $t1.)

Don't just run it, single step it to see what it's doing or not doing.

Note: when debugging code you don't have to use the full length (1000), try it with the smallest reasonable length (2 or so).
